# Expectation of exponential of martingale difference with stochastic volatility

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales, stochastic-integrals

> Let $\sigma_t$ be a stochastic volatility.
> Then is it correct
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dB_s \right) \right]
>  = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_s^2\,ds\right) \right]?
> $$
> If this is correct, then how can we prove?

**What I have tried.**

By using the property of the [exponential martingale](http://math.ucsd.edu/%7Epfitz/downloads/courses/spring05/math280c/expmart.pdf), we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dB_s } \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_s^2\,ds}\left( 1+\int_0^t Z_s \sigma_s\,dB_s \right) \right],
$$
where $Z_s = \exp\left(\int_0^t \sigma_s\,dB_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma_s^2\,ds \right)$.
In my intuition, conditional expectation
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_s^2\,ds}
                 \int_0^t Z_s \sigma_s\,dB_s \middle| \cal{F}_{t-} \right]
 &= e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t-} \sigma_s^2\,ds}
    \int_0^{t-} Z_s \sigma_s dB_s \\
 &+ e^{\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{t} \sigma_s^2\,ds}
   \int_{t-}^{t} Z_s \sigma_s \mathbb{E}[dB_s\mid \cal{F}_{t-}]
\end{split}
$$
is zero by induction, where the equality is from $\sigma_t$ is $\cal{F}_{t-}$-measurable.
However, this seems to be not rigorous enough to consider as a proof.

Comment: I assume that "stochastic volatility" just means adapted process. In that case, I strongly doubt that this is true. Take $\sigma_s:=1_{\{s \le T\}}$, where $T$ is the first time that $(B_t)$ hits $1$, started from zero. Then the left hand side equals $\Bbb E[e^{B_{t\wedge T}}],$ which is bounded above by $e$ since $B_{t\le T} \leq 1$. The right hand side equals $\Bbb E[e^{(t\wedge T)/2}]$. It's well known that $T$ doesn't have a finite first moment, let alone exponential moments, so this diverges pretty quickly as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: What I think **is** true is that you have LHS $\le$ RHS in general, but I'm not 100% sure on that. I will have to check that and get back to you.